# how to disable one signal push notification from wordpress website only for mobile devices

Tags: wordpress, push-notification, onesignal, web-push

I want to disable one signal push notification for my website from all mobile devices.The notification should be visible on website only when user see it through desktop.If anyone uses mobile device the notification should not be visible.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need to make the popup invisible with css.
Use this class `#onesignal-popover-container.slide-up` to customize the mobile css or use this `#onesignal-popover-container.slide-down` for that of computers.
Example:

```
# onesignal-popover-container.slide-up {
display: none !important;
}
```

Use this example to make the popup invisible on mobile.